# How to show if a basis in a matrix vector space is orthonormal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, orthonormal

So I have a matrix vector space consisting of the three matrices:
$$
e_1 = \frac{1}{3}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
e_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & -1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
e_3 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1\\
1 & 0 & -1\\
1 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I am suppose to show that these matrices are orthonormal in the vector space. How is this to be achieved? I know that the requirements are that each base matrix {$e_1, e_2, e_3$} need to have the norm 1 and be pairwise orthogonal, i.e. $e_i \cdot e_j = 0$ for all $i \neq j$ in the vector space.

I can calculate the matrix norm as the maximum absolute column sum, hence $||e_1|| = |\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3}| = 1$. However the norm $||e_2|| = |\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}| = 0$. Therefore $e_2$ does not fulfill the requirements for an orthonormal basis. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Also, how am I suppose to calculate the pairwise ortogonal basis matrices? I.e. how am I suppose to calculate the scalar product of two matrix e.g. $e_1 \cdot e_2$? How does one calculate the scalar product of two matrices?

According to my professor these basis matrices are suppose to give an orthonormal vector space hence my confusion.

Comment: The form of "scalar product" should be given as a condition in your problem. For example, for two real matrices $X, Y$, one possible definition is $\langle X, Y \rangle = \text{Tr}(XY')$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong
Not sure I follow, care to elaborate? What do you mean with Tr? What is $Y´$? Quite a rookie on the notation. 

Are the three matrices orthonormal? Did I calculate the norm of $e_2$ incorrectly?

Comment: A matrix is said orthogonal if its COLUMN are orthogonal and of norm $1$.

Comment: @MarkusAnd You must be told what the inner product is before being asked to prove elements in that space are orthogonal.

Comment: @MarkusAnd The point is that it should not be our job or your job to figure out what the definition is of the scalar product $A \cdot B$ for matrices $A,B$; that should be information that is given by whoever gave you this problem (presumably your professor). One common scalar product (known as the Frobenius scalar product) is 
$$
A \cdot B = \operatorname{Tr}(AB'),
$$
where Tr denotes the trace (sum of the diagonals of a square matrix). Also, it is common to use $\langle A,B \rangle$ to indicate a scalar product rather than $A \cdot B$, which more commonly denotes matrix multiplication.

Comment: @Atmos That definition of "orthogonal" is not relevant to the question being asked

Comment: @MarkusAnd It is indeed the case that these matrices form an orthonormal basis **relative to** the Frobenius inner product, so it is very likely that this is what your professor had in mind. However, this is still something you should verify by checking your textbook or notes, or by contacting your professor.

Comment: @MarkusAnd [Here is the Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product) about the Frobenius inner product. The operation can be succinctly described as the "dot-product of two matrices".

Comment: Many thanks! @BenGrossmann